# Not able to run rspec with Sequel

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, sequel

I am using "rspec_sequel_matchers" gem and followed the steps mentioned in the documentation. But when i run the rspec it says " uninitialized constant RspecSequel (NameError)".
Help much appreciated.

Comment: Post the code for your test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I moved the code:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.include RspecSequel::Matchers
    #...other config..
end
```

from spec_helper.rb to rails_helper.rb

It's working now.